# It is necessary that the script worked 1 time. How?

Tags: javascript, cookies, jquery-cookie

There is a script that writes the count to 3 and then blocks the display of the banner. But the problem is that if you refresh the page again and then the counter starts over again. How to avoid it? Tell me please

```
$('#grandSale').each(function(i) {
  var self = this,
      cookieCounter = $.cookie('disable_banner');
  if (cookieCounter && cookieCounter < 3) {
      cookieCounter++;
      $(self).show();
      $('#topbar').remove();
      $.cookie('disable_banner', cookieCounter, { expires: 365, path: "/" });
  } else {
      $.cookie('disable_banner', 0, { expires: 365, path: "/" });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "else", modify slightly the condition and it should be fine. It seems you reset the counter and start over after reaching 3.

```
$('#grandSale').each(function(i) {
  var self = this,
      cookieCounter = $.cookie('disable_banner') || 0;
  if (cookieCounter < 3) {
      cookieCounter++;
      $(self).show();
      $('#topbar').remove();
      $.cookie('disable_banner', cookieCounter, { expires: 365, path: "/" });
  }
});
```

Comment: Like all .. just time for me to relax. Thank you friend

Comment: I've simplified it a bit further. If it works for you, I'd appreciate you accepting my answer ;)

Comment: I can not put a +. Reputation does not allow (